# Click Button To Get a Random Item Displayed in a Text Box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So, my Mab Libs Program is working fine. The problem comes when I want to create a button to let the user display suggestions from an array. I am using this as the function:

```
  function GetValue(myNameArray)
{
    let myNameArray= new Array["item1","item2","item3"];
    var randomName = myNameArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myNameArray.length)];
  document.getElementById("personOne") = randomName;
}
```

Then, when I go into it and test the code out, it will not show a result in the text box. There's nothing quite like this on the internet and the only results are for general arrays.

Thank you for your help.

Full Code I Am Using:

```
<html><head>
<title>
  Mad Libs Story
</title>
<style>
  h3 {
    text-align: center;
  }

  #input {
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid #5B6DCD 10px;
    padding: 3px;
  }

  #madLibCreation {
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
  }


</style>
<script>

function getVars() {

    var firstPerson = String(document.getElementById("personOne").value);
    var firstAdjective = String(document.getElementById("adjectiveOne").value);
    var secondAdjective = String(document.getElementById("adjectiveTwo").value);
    var thirdAdjective = String(document.getElementById("adjectiveThree").value);
    var secondPerson = String(document.getElementById("personTwo").value);
    var fourthAdjective = String(document.getElementById("adjectiveFour").value);
    var firstNumber = Number(document.getElementById("numberOne").value);
    var thirdPerson = String(document.getElementById("personThree").value);

document.getElementById("madLibCreation").innerHTML = "Dear " + firstPerson + ", Overall, Camp Ad-Lib is " + firstAdjective + ". The camp counselors are " + secondAdjective + " and the food is " + thirdAdjective + ". Today, I met someone named " + secondPerson + "and we became " + fourthAdjective + " friends. I hope to write to you in " + firstNumber + " days. Sincerely, " + thirdPerson + ".";
} 

  function GetValue(myNameArray)
{
    let myNameArray= new Array["item1","item2","item3"];
    var randomName = myNameArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myNameArray.length)];
  document.getElementById("personOne") = randomName;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>
Welcome to "A Letter From Camp"! Have fun!   
</h3>  

  <div id="input">

    <p>
  Name of Person in Room: <input type="text" id="personOne"> <input type="button" value="random" onclick="getValue();">
</p>

<p>
  Adjective: <input type="text" id="adjectiveOne">
  </p>

 <p>
   Adjective: <input type="text" id="adjectiveTwo">
  </p>

  <p>
    Adjective: <input type="text" id="adjectiveThree">
  </p>

  <p>
    Name of Someone: <input type="text" id="personTwo">
  </p>  

  <p>
    Adjective: <input type="text" id="adjectiveFour">
  </p>

  <p>
    Number: <input type="text" id="numberOne">
  </p>

  <p>
   Name of Someone: <input type="text" id="personThree">
  </p>
<p>

<input type="submit" value="Get My MadLib Creation!" onclick="getVars();">
  </p>
  </div>
<p id="madLibCreation"></p>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few syntax errors in your code. The get in the function name should be lowercase, and remove the parameter.

```
        function getValue()
        {
            var myNameArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
            var randomName = myNameArray[Math.floor( Math.random() * myNameArray.length )];
            document.getElementById( "personOne" ).value = randomName;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

you can just do this:

```
document.getElementById("personOne").value = rando(["item1", "item2", "item3"]).value;
```

This implements [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to make the randomness shorter and more readable.